# Is there any automation script to uncheck "Require Password" to never after sleep and turn off sleep in mac?

Tags: macos, applescript

[System Preference Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfwTG.png)

Manual Steps:

1. Open System Preferences
2. Click on "Security and Privacy"
3. Click on "General" tab
4. Uncheck "Require Password" option
5. Disable "Screen Lock"
6. Close "System Preferences"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown below, was tested in **Script Editor** under **macOS Catalina** and **macOS Big Sur** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate setting in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*

```applescript
--  # Check to see if System Preferences is 
--  # running and if yes, then close it.
--  # 
--  # This is done so the script will not fail 
--  # if it is running and a modal sheet is 
--  # showing, hence the use of 'killall' 
--  # as 'quit' fails when done so, if it is.
--  #
--  # This is also done to allow default behaviors
--  # to be predictable from a clean occurrence.

if running of application "System Preferences" then
    try
        tell application "System Preferences" to quit
    on error
        do shell script "killall 'System Preferences'"
    end try
    delay 0.1
end if

--  # Make sure System Preferences is not running before
--  # opening it again. Otherwise there can be an issue
--  # when trying to reopen it while it's actually closing.

repeat while running of application "System Preferences" is true
    delay 0.1
end repeat

--  # Open System Preferences to the General 
--  # tab of the Security and Privacy pane.

tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    reveal anchor "General" of ¬
        pane id "com.apple.preference.security"
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "System Preferences"
        tell its window 1
            --  # Wait until the 'Require password' check box exists.
            set i to 0
            repeat until exists checkbox 1 of tab group 1
                delay 0.1
                set i to i + 1
                if i ≥ 30 then return
            end repeat
            --  # If the target check box is unchecked then quit.
            if value of checkbox 1 of tab group 1 = 0 then
                tell application "System Preferences" to quit
                return
            end if
            --  # Else click the target check box.
            click checkbox 1 of tab group 1
            --  # Wait until the 'Enter the password' sheet exists.
            set i to 0
            repeat until exists sheet 1
                delay 0.1
                set i to i + 1
                if i ≥ 30 then return
            end repeat
            --  # You can uncomment the 'set value of text field 1' and set the password 
            --  # and uncomment 'click button "OK"' to have the rest fully automated, or
            --  # leave them commented, enter your password, press enter and the rest is
            --  # automated. There is also a way to retrieve your password from your
            --  # Keychain, however, that's for you to research and implement.
            tell sheet 1
                -- set value of text field 1 to "PASSWORD"
                -- click button "OK"
                set i to 0
                repeat until exists button "Turn Off Screen Lock"
                    delay 0.5
                    set i to i + 1
                    if i ≥ 30 then return
                end repeat
                click button "Turn Off Screen Lock"
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell

tell application "System Preferences" to quit
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: Thanks a lot for this brilliant script. It worked flawlessly in bigsur 11.3.1 version. Your efforts are much appreciated. @user3439894

Comment: Hey @user3439894 Can you share me the code to set the region and language as well ? Much appreciated.

Comment: @Abhishek Srivastava, RE: "Can you share me the code to set the region and language as well " --  Please use the [**Ask Question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) _button_  at the top right of the page if you have another question you need help with. Thanks.  Also... Please have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68175565/apple-script-to-change-region-and-language-in-macos-bigsur